# Moving many sprites the same distance at the same time with pyglet

Tags: python, sprite, pyglet

I know how to draw them at the same time using batches but I was wondering if there was a way to move a whole batch at once. Do I need to move all sprites individually?

So far I have been doing it like this:

```
tile2 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,0,0,batch = terrain)
tile3 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,10,0,batch = terrain)
tile4 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,20,0,batch = terrain)
tile5 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,30,0,batch = terrain)
tile6 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,40,0,batch = terrain)
tile7 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,50,0,batch = terrain)

tile2.x += 10
tile3.x += 10
tile4.x += 10
```

etc...

But there will be more sprites than this in the finished product (50+ I hope) and moving them all will be pretty tiresome.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to store your objects in an appropriate data structure, such as a [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list):

```
tiles = []
tiles.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,0,0,batch = terrain))
tiles.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1,10,0,batch = terrain))
...
```

A list contains a series of items, which can be accessed individually (`tiles[0], tiles[1]`) or looped through (`for tile in tiles:`). The list can change length and allows you to make the number of tiles you have changeable, without having to hard code lots of variables.

However, this is a very verbose way of doing it, and the much better method is to use a loop:

```
tiles = []
for x in range(0, 51, 10):
    tiles.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1, x, 0, batch = terrain))
```

Here we loop over a range of numbers (from 0 to 51 in steps of 10 - note the use of 51, not 50 - python stops on the last value, not after it, so `range(0, 50, 10)` would yield 0 to 40 in steps of 10.), creating a tile and adding it to our list. Note that if you are using a pre-3.x version of Python, [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) will be faster than [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) as it is returns a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators), not a list. In Python 3.x, this is the behaviour of range.

But Python can be even more elegant, using a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) to create the list easily:

```
tiles = [pyglet.sprite.Sprite(tile1, x, 0, batch = terrain) for x in range(0, 51, 10)]
```

Then to move them, we loop through the list, moving each one as we go:

```
for tile in tiles:
    tile.x += 10
```

In general, doing `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, ... is a sign that something is wrong - using an appropriate data structure will help you do less typing, and make your code more flexible. A good way to think about this is if you are copying and pasting something, then could probably re-factor that code into a reusable function or use a loop to perform the same thing on multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Lattyware answer, which is perfect, but I wanted to say this : since you seem to be new at python/pyglet, you could give a look at cocos2d. It's built on top of pyglet (all you learnt is still true) and has some nice features, such as the one you're looking for. In cocos2d you add sprites to a batch and you can move the batch around with all its children. You also have scrollingLayers if that's what you're looking for...

Comment: I had a look at cocos2d but I'm having trouble getting it to install. :/